# Stripe Custom Recurring Donations

Tags: ruby, sinatra, stripe-payments, recurring-billing

Let me tell you first that Stripe is working perfectly for me with Sinatra.

The thing is, for recurring payments, i have to create plans on Stripe. I have this requirement on my donations page. It works well for fixed amounts for which i created plans.

My question is what should i do when a user enters an amount like $54 for which i don't have plans in stripe? Do i create plans on the fly for each new donation amount? That seems a little too stretched for me. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: did you get a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to do this by the stripe people is to have a subscription for a base amount, and then listen via webhooks for an "invoice created" event. You can then create an invoice item to adjust the amount depending on the user's preferred cost.

The invoice itself is send to the customer an hour after creation so you have that window in which you can add invoice items to adjust the total.

It's explained here...

https://support.stripe.com/questions/metered-subscription-billing

This is not ideal as it would be nicer to have a "set and forget" solution, and it almost seems like the "creating plans on the fly" would be the easier way to go.